# WCF Data service DataServiceKey attribute not working

Tags: wcf, linq-to-sql, wcf-data-services

I am beginning the development of a WCF Data Service project. I received the infamous exception:

> The exception message is 'On data context type
>   'DataClasses1DataContext', there is a top IQueryable property 'table1'
>   whose element type is not an entity type. Make sure that the
>   IQueryable property is of entity type or specify the IgnoreProperties
>   attribute on the data context type to ignore this property

I modified the partial class of my entity with the DataServiceKey attribute. However, I am still receiving the same error. How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Recently this happened to lot of people due to the fact that WCF Data Services used to ship in System.Data.Service.dll, but it ships in Microsoft.Data.Services.dll. So if you DataService<T> is from one of those, but the DataServiceKey attribute is from the other, it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like Vitek said, the solution has been to add refernces to Microsoft.Data.Services and Microsoft.Data.Services.Client to my project that uses the DataServiceKey attribute.